# How do I get qGLWidget to display in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, opengl, qglwidget

I am building a qt interface using Visual-Studio with qt5 add-in.
The interface would have an OpenGL viewer on one side and a series of control buttons on the other.
Rightnow, I have built the necessary UI window with an empty QWidget and a QGLWidget class called MyGLWidget with all the necesasry OpenGL code (initializeGL etc.).

How do I get MyGLWidget to display on QWidget?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. Turned out all you need to do is follow this tutorial.

http://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_OpenGL_QGLWidget.php

Seems like QtCreator method works the same way as Visual-Studio.

Answer (score 0):

try including Qt5OpenGLd.lib in project properties

Comment: Please note that the OP has already found a solution and posted it here.